# Creating One Poll for Blog and Facebook

Tags: facebook, iframe, polling

Hey there I'm running a contest and would love to gather poll results both on my blog and my company Facebook page. Anyone know of a way to do this so the results are fluid? In other words a vote on FB will register in the results the same way it does on the blog. So if there are 50 FB answers and 50 answers from my blog the results page on both will show all 100 responses?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! What have you tried?